# Remove custom taxonomy base from URL

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to change the permalink structure for a custom taxonomy on a custom post type. The custom post type has the slug `resources` and custom taxonomy has the slug `category`. As an example, I've created the taxonomy term `ebooks`. At the moment through the "Permalinks" panel I can get the structure as below:

```
http://localhost/resources/ebooks/my-new-post/
http://localhost/resources/category/ebooks/
```

How can I achieve:

```
http://localhost/resources/ebooks/my-new-post/
http://localhost/resources/ebooks/
```

The latter URL being the archive for the `ebooks` term.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are registering your custom post types, you can simply set the rewrite rules for it like so:

```
$args = array(
        'description' => 'Photograph Post Type',
        'label' => __('Photographs'),
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'photograph'),
);

register_post_type( 'photograph' , $args );
```

If (for some bizarre reason) you don't have access to modify the way in which your custom post types are being registered, try setting the "category base" to "." within the Permalinks menu in your admin panel, and make sure that your permalink structure is set to */%category%/%postname%/*. That's worked for me in the past.